# How to create alias of a certain command to point to the primary one

Tags: ubuntu, python, windows

Hello I am a beginner in ubuntu and using python3 for my some of the deployments, also same deployments are tested on windows so every time I push/pull changes between Linux and windows I encounter a irritating issue.

Windows recognize python3 as `py` e.g. `py someprogram.py` will run the program but it does not work in Linux.

In Linux the command is `python3` e.g. `sudo python3 someprograme.py` which is not recognized in windows I want a common command alias so that there must be no changes while pushing or pulling the code.

Comment: Are you running Linux or Windows? Is this about the WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux)?

Comment: This can be achieved with a symbolic link named *py* that points to the path of python3.

Comment: No i am using both OS in different machines but the code is developed and tested on window and push the code is pulled in Ubuntu machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in linux, you could add this as an alias command...

```
alias py="sudo python3"
```

However, this only makes it temporary. Add `alias py="sudo python3"` at the end of `~/.bashrc` to make the alias persist between sessions.

since windows already uses `py`, you wont need to change anything in windows.
best!

EDIT: Updated for clarity.

Comment: Yes this was exactly i was looking for